# PHP auto-assigning query string variables without me doing anything

Tags: php

I came across this when I realized I had a script that was working, *but shouldn't be*. I tested it by making a one line script as follows:

```
<?php
echo "<br>lang - $lang"; 
?>
```

When I run the script with query string `?lang=japanese` it outputs:

```
lang - japanese
```

What the hell? No `$_GET` or `$_REQUEST` statements or anything but that one line. How is this happening???

Comment: It's likely that the `register_globals` directive is turned on: http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php it's a bad feature, it should ideally be turned off

Comment: So it is. I had no idea it worked like that. Of course, like I said, I found this out when I realized a script was working that shouldn't be (I hadn't used a $_GET or $_REQUEST statement). Now I wonder how many of my other scripts are futzed in the same way...

Answer (score 2):

Like [Pekka](https://stackoverflow.com/users/187606/pekka) said, it is likely you have [`register_globals`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php) turned on in your configuration. This is usually regarded as a security risk and should be turned off.

The feature itself was actually removed as of PHP 5.4.0